# Friendly_Id: id is slug, but url still displays object id attribute (?id=)

Tags: parameters, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-plugins, friendly-id

I'm trying to implement the Friendly_Id gem in my rails 4 app and have hit a roadblock.

The gem is working, but the url still isn't pretty. It looks like this:

http://www.example.com/project/featured?id=project-name

The gem is working because the id parameter is now a slug, however I have no idea how to remove the "?id=" and replace it with a slash? Is that possible? Did I miss a step?

**Controller:**

```
  def featured
    @project = Project.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**Model:**

```
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
```

**View:**

```
     <% @projects.each do |project| %>

        <%= link_to project_featured_path(:id => project.slug) do %>

            <%= project.title %>

        <% end %>

    <% end %>
```

**Relevant Routes:**

```
get "project/featured"

match 'project' => 'project#index', :as => :project, via: [:get, :post]

resources :projects do
  member do
    get :featured
  end
end

match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)', via: [:get, :post]
```

I've also referenced a previous app of mine running Friendly_Id in rails 3. It doesn't seem to have this problem... can't remember if I'm just missing a step.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

**Update:**

After substituting:

`project_featured_path(:id => project.slug)`

for [pearlshareteam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3227797/pearlshareteam) answer:

`project_featured_path(project)`

my url looks a bit better but is still not working. It looks like this:

http://example.com/project/featured.project-one

there is a period instead of a slash. On testing I found that if I just replaced the dot with a slash the correct page is actually generated.

Is it just a problem with my link_to formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on your routes so it might be handy to post them as well but if they look like this:

```
resources :projects do
  member do
    get :featured
  end
end
```

I would hazard a guess that the syntax you want is:

```
project_featured_path(project)
```

I checkout out the friendly_id [source](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/base.rb#L242) and it seems that friendly_id overrides the active record 'to_param' method. This is called by the rails path/url helpers to construct urls from AR objects so will construct the url with the url slug.

Also see the finder methods in the [source](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/finder_methods.rb) where it looks like friendly ID overrides the 'find' method. It first looks for a friendly id and if that fails it falls back to looking it up by the traditional id.

I think that should help or hopefully be a hint in the right direction.